# CSS filter applied to all elements of my webpage

Tags: html, css

I put a button centered in my page but the css filter that i have write for html tag is also applied to my button. How an i avoid that ?

[image]

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="button">
        <a href="#">START EXPERIENCE</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
html { 
  background: url(../img/cover2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-filter: brightness(0.5);
  filter: brightness(0.5);
  // Browser Specific
  -moz-filter: brightness(0.5);
  -o-filter: brightness(0.5);
  -ms-filter: brightness(0.5);
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.button {
    position: absolute;
    left: 40%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-filter: none;
}

.button a {
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 2px white solid;
    color: white;
    padding: 25px;
    padding-left: 100px;
    padding-right: 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 22px;
}

.button a:hover {
    background: white;
    color: black;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: not sure if you can, see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22584671/make-a-parent-div-webkit-filter-not-affect-children

Comment: I would suggest rather giving a filter property to `html` element  create a container div and then give a property to that div.

Comment: That would still be an issue for any parent of the button with the same property.

Comment: @KheemaPandey That is definitely a good thing to do regarding semantics, you should never explicitly style your html element.  That said, moving the filter to the body tag, or any other container div will not solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have applied the technique below to a single div but it can be extended to the page as a whole.

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/kGvoF)

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/sports/1/" alt="" />
    <div class="button">Some Text</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
    width:400px;
  height:400px;
  margin:25px auto;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper img {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  -webkit-filter: brightness(0.5);
  // Browser Specific
  -moz-filter: brightness(0.5);
  -o-filter: brightness(0.5);
  -ms-filter: brightness(0.5);
    filter: brightness(0.5);
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  -wekbit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  color:black;
  font-weight: bold;
  border:1px solid white;
  padding:1em;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/400/sports/1/);
  background-position: center center;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Applying it to the HTML tag will apply this style globally across anything else your HTML will contain. As a general rule of thumb, you should **never** style your HTML tag explicitly. That's not its intention.

Any elements inside the parent element where the filter is applied will also be affected.

Answer (score 0):

just edit your background picture with a 0.5 opacity on photoshop, leave the `html` tag alone and set that image as your `body` background picture

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
    <i class="shadow"></i>
    <div class="button">
        <a href="#">START EXPERIENCE</a>
</div>
</body>
```

css

```
body {
  background: url(http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/cute_baby_in_autumn-wide.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.shadow{
  position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-filter: brightness(0.5);
  filter: brightness(0.5);
  -moz-filter: brightness(0.5);
  -o-filter: brightness(0.5);
  -ms-filter: brightness(0.5);
}

.button {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20%;
    top: 50%;
    z-index:2;
}

.button a {
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 2px solid white;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    padding-left: 100px;
    padding-right: 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-align:center;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.button a:hover {
    background: white;
    color: black;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```