# Want to make the whole page in grayscale except specified div

Tags: css, selector, grayscale

I have a css code that could make the whole page in grayscale.

```
<style type="text/css">
html {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}
</style>
```

I now want to embed an iframe inside a div that would not be affected. I have searched about the solution and fount :not selector. When I refer to 6.6.7 at http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation I think i have found the solution because it may work even I put html as my css selector

```
html|:not(x)
```

So I changed the code just like the above code but nothing changed. I was worried about the problem is caused by the design of my website so I decided to code them in jsfiddle in the most simple HTML

```
<div id="abc" class="abc"><font color="red">This should be a normal text.</font></div>
<font color="red">This should be an affected text.</font>
```

In CSS

```
html|*:not(.abc) {
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
-moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
filter: grayscale(100%); }
```

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/4vxyqdye/1/
PS: In the previous version I used :not(.abc) only but all elements become grayscale.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make a parent div webkit-filter not affect children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22584671/make-a-parent-div-webkit-filter-not-affect-children)

Answer (score 4):

Think in the weight of selectors, html is a general selector, less heavy than more specific selectors, like clases or IDs, if you do something like :

```
html {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}

html .class-you-wanna-exlude {
   -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
   -moz-filter: grayscale(0%);
   filter: grayscale(0%);
}
```

i think this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Apply the filter to all children of `<body>`, excluding the class specified, with:

 `body :not(.class-to-not-filter) { filter }`

[Have an example!](http://jsbin.com/nuhuyo/1/edit)

CSS

```
body :not(.exclude) {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.exclude {
    background: yellow;
    height: 100px;
}

.gray {
    background: purple;
    height: 100px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="exclude"></div> 
<div class="gray"></div>
```