# Is there a way to have images with original color if body has a filter of greyscale?

Tags: javascript, css

I am using thew following piece of code to show body in greyscale

```
.body{
       -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
       filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

but I want images to be of their original color so I am using

```
img{
        -webkit-filter:none;
        filter:none; 
}
```

I am also making use of the following piece of code

```
img{
       -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
       filter: grayscale(0%);
}
```

but it does not work.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Did you check this already? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26087286/want-to-make-the-whole-page-in-grayscale-except-specified-div

Answer (score 1):

You can't apply a filter to a parent element and then exclude a child from that filter.

If you apply grayscale to the `<body>` you can't remove it from any div within the body.

The workaround is to only apply grayscale to all element that need to be grayscale but I imagine that would take a bit of planing ahead and rearranging the DOM quite a bit.

The other workaround is to mask the grayscale but that needs SVG filters and is more complex.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily update your first selector which sets the filter on the `body` element to exclude any images:

```css
body :not(img) {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
          filter: grayscale(100%);
}

p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://placekitten.com/200/287" />

<p>Hello</p>
```

Comment: That would work only for <img> that are direct children of the <body> tag (very uncommon) https://jsfiddle.net/5qwLuade/