# How to stop a child div inheriting some of a parents divs attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, inheritance

I have created a div which has an image on it :

```
.middleBlockDiv{
    content:url("./images/blockhead.png");
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: rgba(70,130,180,1);
    float: left;
    z-index:2;
    opacity: 0.8;
    border: 4px solid white;
    border-radius: 30px 15px;
    clear:both;
}
```

and I have a child div :

```
.coinDiv{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: gold;
    float: left;
    z-index:2;
    border: 4px solid white;
    border-radius: 50px;
    clear:both;
}
```

If i dont put an image into the parent div so the css of the parent div is like so :

```
.middleBlockDiv{
        display: inline-block;
        background-color: rgba(70,130,180,1);
        float: left;
        z-index:2;
        opacity: 0.8;
        border: 4px solid white;
        border-radius: 30px 15px;
        clear:both;
    }
```

The child div gets shown, however, if i keep the image in, the child div doesn't get shown. It's in the DOM but not shown onscreen.

I think it may be because of inheritance, as the child div may be inheriting the image.

How do I stop the child div inheriting the image from the parent ?

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/8xyk2ucb/

Comment: Can you add your HTML to the question, or better still a working http://jsfiddle.net. I would imagine that it's not a inheritance issue, but instead due to the `content:` you're adding.

Comment: Hope that this poste helps you.
[posted by makville][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080365/css-to-prevent-child-element-from-inheriting-parent-styles

Comment: Why do you insert the image into the dom using the content attribute?  Why don't you just use it as a background image?

Comment: i didnt think you could do that, shall give it a go now thanks @HaukurHaf

Comment: that worked perfectly, thanks @HaukurHaf. If you want to put it as an answer ill gladly accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the user @HaukurHaf mentioned to me to use background-image instead of content, that helped me solve my problem.

So my code looks like this :

```
.middleBlockDiv{
    background-image:url("./images/blockhead.png");
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: rgba(70,130,180,1);
    float: left;
    z-index:2;
    opacity: 0.8;
    border: 4px solid white;
    border-radius: 30px 15px;
    clear:both;
}

.coinDiv{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: gold;
    float: left;
    z-index:2;
    border: 4px solid white;
    border-radius: 50px;
    clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

CSS rules are inherited by default - hence the "cascading" name. To get what you want you need to use !important:

example:

```
middleBlockDiv
{
  ....;
}
coinDiv
{
  // any rule you want here, followed by !important
}
```