# Polymer "custom-style" body and html styles leaking to local dom

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a `custom-styles` file that defines html and body like this:

```
<style is="custom-style">
html, body { color: #ffffff; background-color: #212121; }
</style>
```

The problem I have is that those styles are leaking to custom elements in their local dom, making the font color white.

This should not be happening according to the documentation here: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#custom-style

My question is: Is this the default behavior or is this a bug?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this is not related to `custom-style` but to `body`. You'd need to change the `color` and `background-color` of your elements to something else than `inherit` which is the default.

See also [CSS to prevent child element from inheriting parent styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080365/css-to-prevent-child-element-from-inheriting-parent-styles)