# How to exclude specific the form from the css applied to body

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, css

If i have a `form` in body with specific style and i want to exclude this `form` from this style(the body style) .

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="demo-containers">
            <div class="demo-container" id="decorationZone">
                <h4>Student Schedule</h4>

                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Registeration Number</legend>
                    <label for="<%= UsernameBox.ClientID %>" runat="server">RegNum:&nbsp;</label>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="UsernameBox" Width="150px" TabIndex="7"></asp:TextBox>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
......
</body>
```

---

The problem is : the body has a `css` and i want this style not applied on my form ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just override the style you dont want. Lets say that your body has a red background, so in your form just override the background color to white. I have created a small demo like this below.

[Demo](http://codepen.io/adibM/pen/PNVjmb)

```
body{
  background-color:red;
}
form{
  background-color:white;
}
```

There is a property called [all](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-cascade/#all-shorthand) in the CSS3 inheritance module. It works like this:

```
form {
  all: default;
}
```

Comment: I want to override everything, Should i create a rule for every one exist for the body !

Comment: yes, you will have to override all those style for your form tag or you could just remove those styles from the body tag.

Comment: I just want to exclude the form from the body style !

Comment: yes you will have to override all the body styles in the form.

Comment: This question answers your query

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080365/css-to-prevent-child-element-from-inheriting-parent-styles

Comment: Why downvote the question !!

Comment: it is a duplicate question.. if had you searched a bit more, you would have had your solution.

Comment: Okay , thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS negation and leave out what you don't want to inherit from `body`:

```
body :not(form) { 
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately if you apply a body style on a page it will affect all the elements of the page.
I think you can only redefine the property of your body in your form style.
in the css you should recover your form that you want to exclude from your style

```
#form1
```

And you will have to overwrite the css property that you don't want.