# How to select text within li using css

Tags: css

I have following HTML markup
[image]

How do i select text inside this

As you can see inside that

there is a div i dont want to affect contents on that div.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080365/css-to-prevent-child-element-from-inheriting-parent-styles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't select only that text. So style the div too:

```css
ul,
li div {
  color: black;
}
li {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    Text
    <div>Div Text</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    Text
    <div>Div Text</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Text nodes can't be selected with CSS. You have to give some rules to the li, and then give rules to the div inside the li to override the styles that it gets from its parent, or wrap the text on some other element like a span.

Answer (score 1):

With the regular CSS methods you can't do that.

I suggest to put a `<span>` around it and assig a class to it which you can style.

Comment: That worked, thank you for the suggestion.