# Apply style for all descendants except link not working

Tags: html, css

I have a scenario to apply color to all descendants except the anchor tag `<a>`.

```css
 .texts *:not(a) {
      color: red;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="texts">
      <div class="wrapper">
        sample text in this
      </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
        sample text in this
      </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
        sample text in this
      </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
        sample text in this
      </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
        <a href="#">TEST</a>
      </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
        sample text in this
      </div>
    </div>
```

This is working. But when i inspect i can see that the style is being applied to the anchor tag element. I am converting all the styles applied to inline later. So the color that is striked while inspecting is taken as inline. Why does that happen. See the[image: screenshot]

Comment: "child elements (direct and indirect)" — Children are children, there is no such thing as an "indirect" child. The terms you are looking for a *children* and *descendants*.

Comment: @Quentin Ok. How can i modify my requirment ?

Comment: Replace the phrase "child elements (direct and indirect)" with "descendants"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `color` style is *not* being explicitly applied to your anchor element.

The default value for `color` is `inherit`, so even though you have excluded anchors from your selector, it'll still inherit the colour from its parent, `div.wrapper`.

FYI; your inspector actually states this:

[image]

Comment: Is there a solution to this ? Because when i convert this style as inline, red color is applied to anchor tag

Comment: This is by design, so it's not exactly a *problem* as such. You can change the `color` style of your anchor tags to anything you'd like to prevent inheriting, e.g. `.texts .wrapper a{ color: green; }`.

Comment: I want the default color of link. Is there any way i can prevent anchor tag from being style applied ?

Comment: @melvin — You **have** the default colour of the link. You can tell that because the browser stylesheet rule (with the selector `a:-webkit-any-link`) is overriding the inherited colour (which is crossed out).

Comment: But when i convert it to inline, red color is applied to link

Comment: @melvin — Then something is wrong with the way you convert to inline.

Comment: Set color of the tag to initial

Comment: @George Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

because the anchor is not a child of .texts

check this out

```
<div class="texts">
  <div class="wrapper">
    sample text in this
  </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
    sample text in this
  </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
    sample text in this
  </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
    sample text in this
  </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">TEST</a>
  </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
    sample text in this
  </div>
  <a href="#">TEST2</a>
</div>

.texts *:not(a) {
  color: red;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

the css is not applied to the test2 child anchor :)

Comment: Ok. But when i convert this style to inline, the red color is applied to the anchor as inline style

Comment: because in inline you directly add styles. you can't select specific elements

Comment: I have added `:not()` then why does it target `<a>` when converting to inline

Comment: Hi Melvin, you can not use this selector in inline -style. That's why

Comment: maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080365/css-to-prevent-child-element-from-inheriting-parent-styles

Comment: Thanks for your time. I have upvoted for your effort