# I'm using SpryTabbedPanels in Dreamweaver and I need to change the menu font size only?

Tags: css

In SpryTabbedPanels.css trying to add this code

```
.TabbedPanels {
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: tahoma;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    clear: none;
    width: 100%; /* IE Hack to force proper layout when preceded by a paragraph. (hasLayout Bug)*/
}
```

But the font size here apply to the content too, But I need it to apply only to the head menu.
thanks

Comment: I believe the css class is getting inherited to the child elements as well,check this SO, it could help you to some extent.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958170/how-do-i-prevent-css-inheritance

Comment: Add changes to .TabbedPanelsTab class (at the top of the css file) if you want just headings changed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can do this in an 'easy' way. All the parent css rules get inherited by child nodes unless overwritten. So if you want to make sure that all the elements inside `.TabbedPanels` will not inherit its font, use:

```
.TabbedPanels <elements you need styled> {
   font-family: <your desired font>;
}
```

For example, this will reset font of all the nodes within `.TabbedPanels`:

```
.TabbedPanels * {
   font-family: auto;
}
```