# CSS : How to disable parent-child inheterance?

Tags: html, css, inheritance

My question is very simple and i just need to know if this is possible or not.

this is a simple version of my HTML & css codes

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="ch1">CHILD 1</div>
    <div class="ch2">CHILD 2</div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.parent {background-color:red}
```

I want to know if it is possible to prevent "CHILD1 div from **inheriting** the **background-color** property from its parent element

**P.S.** I don't mean overriding that property but preventing the inheritance like it never had a **background-color** propert.

Thank you

Comment: In this case it's not inheriting, but because you don't have a `background-color` set on the child divs, you'll see the red background.

Comment: The child doesn't actually inherit `background-color`. The child's background is transparent. You're seeing a red background because it's sitting on top of something red, but that means nothing to the child; if you position it so it's outside of its parent, it won't have a red background.

Comment: my problem is that i need that child element to be transparent, and show what is already beyond the div parent. But in my case the .parent div already has a bg color...

Comment: I don't think you understand the concept of backgrounds...

Comment: So in short `"My question is very simple and i just need to know if this is possible or not."` .. The answer is no, it is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color

background-color is not inherited, the default value is transparent。 so the background-color of the parent will be seen as if it is set for the child.

Initial value: transparent
Applies to ： all elements
Inherited ： no

Comment: Good point. Raises the question what the OP is trying to do in the first place

Answer (score 2):

The child doesn't actually inherit background-color. The child's background is transparent. You're seeing a red background because it's sitting on top of something red, but that means nothing to the child; if you position it so it's outside of its parent, it won't have a red background.

What it sounds like you're actually asking for is for the child element to cut a hole in the parent's background so that the element behind it shows through. Is that right?

If that's what you're after, then no, you can't do this.

The closest you can get to it is the `clip` CSS property.

You would define `clip` on the parent's CSS as a rectangle which covers the same space as the child element. (of course, you'd have to know in advance the dimensions of the child to be able to do this)

This would be a way to achieve what you're after, but `clip` does have some major limitations, not least of which is that it only works if the element is `position:absolute` or `position:fixed`.

You can read more about `clip` here: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/01/16/understanding-the-css-clip-property/

Another alternative might be to use SVG instead of HTML for this. It's easier to achieve this kind of effect using SVG, since it is a proper graphics language.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote you a haiku.

> > This can not be done.
> >
> > To attempt it would be wrong.
> >
> > Kids would weep and cry.

In your example, simply override the background color (which as mentioned, is not inherited but transparent). Or rearrange your HTML. I don't understand the reticence. If this is making part of your code difficult, post the entire problem and we will help you with it.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/958227/1669208) Is another answer with a little bit more information.

**Alternative**

If you are concerned about the maintainability of your code base, especially with a large number of colors and styles. You might look into [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) as a way to overcome the inherit limitations of CSS. Both of these frameworks offer features such as nested operators and variables.

Comment: How long until someone flags this as "not an answer"?

Comment: @cHao: I know, but I'm sure someone's bound to flag it based on the statement "I am bored" or the haiku.