# Styling nested unordered lists separately from one another

Tags: css

I have navigation menus that look something like this:

```
<ul id="nav1">
    <li>Link 1</li>
    <li>
        Link 2
        <ul id="subnav1">
            <li>Sublink 1</li>
            <li>Sublink 2</li>
            <li>Sublink 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Link 3</li>
    <li>Link 4</li>
    <li>Link 5</li>
</ul>
```

I have a bunch of CSS styling that looks like this:

```
ul#nav1{ … styles … }
ul#nav1 > li{ … styles … }
```

But I really don't want the styling to cascade down to the "subnav1" menu, yet it is for some reason. I thought the "greater than" sign in my CSS would prevent that. How can I make the "subnav1" menu have its own styling, without anything cascading down from "nav1"?

ACTUAL CODE:

```
<ul id="nav2" class="clearfix">
    <li>
        <div class="nav2hl"></div><a class="drop" href="products.htm">Products</a>
        <div class="menu1bg" classclearfix">
            <ul class="menu1">
                <li>RETAIL</li>
                <li><a href="retail-hot-dogs.htm">Hot Dogs</a></li>
                <li><a href="retail-ring-bologna.htm">Ring Bologna</a></li>
                <li><a href="retail-hams.htm">Hams</a></li>
                <li><a href="retail-make-it-easy-hams.htm">Make it Easy Hams</a></li>
                <li><a href="retail-sausage-brats.htm">Sausage/Brats</a></li>
                <li><a href="retail-deli-meats.htm">Deli Meats</a></li>
                <li><a href="retail-other.htm">Other</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="menu1">
                <li>FOOD SERVICE</li>
                <li><a href="food-service-hot-dogs.htm">Hot Dogs</a></li>
                <li><a href="food-service-ring-bologna.htm">Ring Bologna</a></li>
                <li><a href="food-service-hams.htm">Hams</a></li>
                <li><a href="food-service-sausage-brats.htm">Sausage/Brats</a></li>
                <li><a href="food-service-deli-meats.htm">Deli Meats</a></li>
                <li><a href="food-service-roller-bites.htm">Roller Bites</a></li>
                <li><a href="food-service-pizza-toppings.htm">Pizza Toppings</a></li>
                <li><a href="food-service-other.htm">Other</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li></li>
    <li><div class="nav2hl"></div><a class="drop" href="recipes.htm">Recipes</a></li>
    <li></li>
    <li><div class="nav2hl"></div><a href="family-fun.htm">Family<br />Fun</a></li>
    <li></li>
    <li><div class="nav2hl"></div><a href="special-offers.htm">Special<br />Offers</a></li>
    <li></li>
    <li><div class="nav2hl"></div><a href="newsworthy.htm">Note &amp;<br />Newsworthy</a></li>
    <li></li>
    <li><div class="nav2hl"></div><a href="retailer-locator.htm">Retailer<br />Locator</a></li>
    <li></li>
    <li><div class="nav2hl"></div><a href="contact-us.htm">Contact<br />Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
div#nav2bg{background:#e8dcab url('../img/bg_nav2.jpg') repeat-y top center;}
ul#nav2{float:right;margin:0;padding:0;list-style-type:none;}
ul#nav2 > li{display:inline-block;position:relative;float:left;margin:0;padding:0;}
ul#nav2 > li:nth-child(even){width:1px;height:93px;background:transparent url('../img/bg_nav2_divider.png') no-repeat top left;}
ul#nav2 > li a,ul#nav2 > li a:visited{display:inline-block;position:relative;width:107px;height:67px;margin:0;padding:26px 0 0 0;color:#856e46;text-align:center;text-transform:uppercase;}
ul#nav2 > li a.drop{height:59px;padding-top:34px;}
ul#nav2 > li a:hover{color:#f4eed6;}
ul#nav2 > li div.nav2hl{display:none;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:107px;height:93px;background-color:#af9764;}

div.menu1bg{position:absolute;top:93px;left:50%;z-index:999;width:488px;height:297px;margin-left:-244px;background:rgba(237,230,206,0.95);}
ul.menu1{float:left;width:244px;height:297px;margin:0;padding:0;list-style-type:none;}
```

Comment: What exactly is cascading down? Also you can always add a class to the list items in each level. Show some code and be more specific

Comment: The test site is at http://bbdesign.com/berksfoods.com (the area under the Products button is taking on some of the styling).

Comment: Can you be more specific, give me an example of which exact style

Comment: I edited the original question with some code. A bunch of the ul#nav2 styles seem to be cascading down to the ul.menu1 item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

```
ul#nav2 > li a, ul#nav2 > li a:visited { ... }
```

This will target all the anchors under ul#nav2 > li, since the anchor in your second level nav qualifies so it will take styles from it

Use

```
ul#nav2 > li > a, ul#nav2 > li > a:visited { ... }
```

to target the more specific anchor, you might need to apply this at multiple places

Comment: I saw this just shortly before you wrote. You are correct, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to override them.

A similar question was answered here:
[How do I prevent CSS inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958170/how-do-i-prevent-css-inheritance)

Answer (score 0):

The `>` is exactly what you should be using.

I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/43vbK/1/) for some examples of technicalities of using `>`:

For example, #nav1 changes the `list-style` and only the `#nav1 > li`'s are affected (#subnav1 is still the default circle):

```
#nav1 > li{list-style-type:square;}
```

HOWEVER, should you do something like `#nav2 > li{background-color: yellow;}`, the `background-color` of `#subnav2` with still be `yellow` because it is nested WITHIN `#nav > li`

Comment: Ah, I found the problem. I had some styling that was #nav2 > li a (but I forgot to put the > before the "a" so it cascaded downward).

Comment: Nice! Glad you figured it out :)