# Assign CSS class to full <tr> but not one of the <td> tags

Tags: html, css

I have a css class on table `<tr>` tags but i want to stop it from being added on one `<td>`

is this possible? can i add a seperate class to the specific `<td>` to stop the `<tr>`'s class being added?

Comment: you can override or reset it in the td, any example code?

Comment: yes you can have a specific class for it `<td class='uniqueStyle'>`

Comment: just give that TD it's own class name and assign it, undoing whatever the TR does

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I prevent CSS inheritance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958170/how-do-i-prevent-css-inheritance)

Comment: Why not? Can you provide an example to clarify what you want?

Comment: Why not? Can you provide an example to clarify what you want?

Comment: Some example code is always useful so others can understand more easily what you want to do.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the `:not` selector (which you can use to filter all bar the selector within the brackets):

```css
table td:not(.this) {
  background: red;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td class="this">2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

Alternatively, you could use a class selector if you wanted to style it differently (rather than not at all):

```css
table tr {
  background: red;
  color: blue;
}
.this {
  background: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td class="this">2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tr.MyClassName{
    // styling goes here
}
```

That should only style the `tr` but not the `td`.

Comment: This styles `tr`s with the MyClassName class, but doesn't apply the styling to ANY subsequent `td`. The OP wants to know how to omit the styling for only a specific `td` element, not all of them.