# Angular route to have no inherited CSS

Tags: angular, css, angular-ui-router

I would like to have a url for an angular project which has no CSS inherited from the main CSS file. I have looked into it but when I try I keep getting the inherited CSS.

I only want to use the CSS provided on the component itself.

Comment: Are you talking about AngularJS or Angular 5?

Comment: Please provide more concrete information. Where is the main CSS added? What styles do you not have to be applied? How is that related to the router? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958170/how-do-i-prevent-css-inheritance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not related to Angular, that's just normal browser behavior.

You can use shadow DOM where supported

```
@Component({
  selector: '...',
  viewEncapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native,
})
export class MyComponent {}
```

I don't know which browsers already support that.