# How to exclude a css class for a tag in the same div/ tr?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a div as follows:

```
<tr class="section">
   <td>some content here</td>
   <td class="info">content 2 here</td>
</tr>
```

css:

```
.section{
   //style here
 }

.info{
   //another style here
}
```

In this case, i don't want to apply the *section* style in the in *info*.

How to do that?

Comment: That HTML is invalid. `td` can only be a child of `tr`.

Comment: it's invalid as said but if we consider them span ... you cannot, you simply need to revert back the style BUT not all of them (display,opacity, etc etc)

Comment: Also, you cannot prevent style inheritance - you can only overwrite unwanted styles coming from a parent element.

Comment: Asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958170/how-do-i-prevent-css-inheritance)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:not` selector in the following way: `.section *:not(.info)`

(I changed your HTML a bit to make it valid)

```css
.section{
   color: red;
 }

.section *:not(.info){
   color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
   <span>some content here</span>
   <span class="info">content 2 here</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Johannes, That's good, but the _section_ class static one, should not change anything here, for the "_content 2_" i just wanted to exclude the "section" style.

Comment: why you re-opened this question too ... you don't like when we close a question you answer ...

Comment: the so-called "duplicate" is from 2009, and under the accepted answer there is a comment (with 9 upvotes) that this answer is outdated

Comment: @Johannes that doesn't make this any less of a duplicate. There are 10 other answers on that question.

Answer (score 0):

Your should use td only if you are using an HTML table instead you can use div's or a more semantic tag... [check here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp)

In the css you can overwrite your parent class when you are inside of it like this..

```
.section .info{
   //overwrite style here
 }
```

Comment: Yeah, I use these td inside HTML table.

Comment: Thank you @Renzo