# Why does the child selector select all descendants?

Tags: css

The child selector should select the immediate children contained by an element. But in the following code, the selector `div > ul > li` select all descendant `<li>` of `<div>`. I have no idea why the child selector expands its scope?

```css
div>ul>li {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3
      <ul>
        <li>Item 31</li>
        <li>Item 32</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: color is inherited

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958170/how-do-i-prevent-css-inheritance

Answer (score 5):

If you take a look at the page in Chrome or Firefox's developer tools, you'll see what's happening. The selector isn't applying to the further descendants—instead, they're inheriting the `color` from their parent.

By default, the `color` property isn't set. This is equivalent to setting `color: inherit;`—in other words, it means "since I have no special instructions, I'll do whatever my parent is doing". So when you set a color for an element, it'll *also* apply to all that element's descendants, unless any of them specify a `color` of their own.

Comment: And even though [`text-decoration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration) isn't an inherited property, it also applies to descendants. _"Text decorations are drawn across descendant text elements. This means that if an element specifies a text decoration, then a child element can't remove the decoration."_

Comment: @j08691 Very good point! I can edit that into my answer, or you can post it as an answer of your own if you'd like the rep for it.

Answer (score 1):

@Draconis' answer is off to a good start, but the comments suggest there is no solution to the underlining. So here is a solution.

```css
/* Set all list elements to a default value. change this to what you need it to be */
li {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/* Then set the inner ULs to full width inline-block; which will prevent the
   text-decoration from inheriting into them */
div>ul ul {
  display:inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
}

div>ul>li {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3
      <ul>
        <li>Item 31</li>
        <li>Item 32</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```